# getting " Type Error : $(...).autocomplete is not a function" error using jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, laravel-7

I'm locked into a jQuery ui issue. I have done a form that I need to autocomplete all the field based on client id. It is like if I'm typing the id of an existing client, all the fields should be autofill with all that's client values from database table like fisrtname , last name, address, date-of-birth, but for the first i'm just trying to test if jquery Ui is working and I got the "$(...).autocomplete is not a function" error in console. It is not from Jquery because I have done also a notification system and i dysplay all notification with Jquery and it is working , I think That it's from jQuery UI. I have tried all possible solutions that I found with no success. Thank's in advance ! Good day to everybody! :)

This is My layouts.app

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <meta name="userId" content="{{Auth::check() ? Auth::user()->id : '' }}">
    
    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('jqueryui/jquery-ui.min.js')}}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
    
        window.Laravel = {!! json_encode([  
            'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
        ]); !!}

        
    </script>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    {{-- <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet"> --}}

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('jqueryui/jquery-ui.min.css')}}">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="{{asset('assets/images/favicon.png')}}">
    <title>S.C. Amanet Stefany IFN S.R.L.</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="{{asset('assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- morris CSS -->
    <link href="{{asset('assets/plugins/morrisjs/morris.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="{{asset('css/style.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
   
    <!-- You can change the theme colors from here -->
    <link href="{{asset('css/colors/blue.css')}}" id="theme" rel="stylesheet">
    {{-- <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"> --}}
</head>
<body>
 .... this is my content ....


<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>

 {{-- <script src="{{asset('assets/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js')}}"></script> --}}
 {{-- <script src="{{asset('js/jquery.js')}}"></script> --}}


<!-- Bootstrap tether Core JavaScript -->
<script src="{{asset('assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/popper.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
<!-- slimscrollbar scrollbar JavaScript -->
<script src="{{asset('js/jquery.slimscroll.js')}}"></script>
<!--Wave Effects -->
<script src="{{asset('js/waves.js')}}"></script>
<!--Menu sidebar -->
<script src="{{asset('js/sidebarmenu.js')}}"></script>
<!--stickey kit -->
<script src="{{asset('assets/plugins/sticky-kit-master/dist/sticky-kit.min.js')}}"></script>
<!--Custom JavaScript -->
{{-- <script src="{{asset('js/custom.js')}}"></script> --}}
<script src="{{asset('js/custom.min.js')}}"></script>
{{-- <script src="{{asset('js/jquery-ui.js')}}"></script> --}}


<!-- ============================================================== -->
<!-- This page plugins -->
<!-- ============================================================== -->
<!--sparkline JavaScript -->
<script src="{{asset('assets/plugins/sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js')}}"></script>
<!--morris JavaScript -->
<script src="{{asset('assets/plugins/raphael/raphael-min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('assets/plugins/morrisjs/morris.min.js')}}"></script>
<!-- Chart JS -->
<script src="{{asset('js/dashboard1.js')}}"></script>
<!-- ============================================================== -->
<!-- Style switcher -->
<!-- ============================================================== -->
<script src="{{asset('assets/plugins/styleswitcher/jQuery.style.switcher.js')}}"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

This is my view with that form

```
                                     <div class="form-group row ml-1 mb-1">
                                        <label for="example-text-input" class="col-3 col-form-label pt-0" style="min-width: 80px;">Serie B.I./C.I.:</label>
                                        <div class="col-3 pl-0">
                                            <input class="form-control input-height pl-1 pr-1" name="serie" type="text" value="" id="">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-4 pl-0">
                                            <input class="form-control input-height pl-1 pr-1"  name="nr_id" type="text" value="" id="cltId" > //this #cltId ----------
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

And this is my resource/js/app.js with the jQuery code that I need

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#cltId").autocomplete({
        source: [
            'Apple',
            'Banana',
            'Orange',
        ]
    });
});
```

Any suggestion ? Have I added something that I shouldn't ? Have I write the code in wrong way ? I can not find the mistake ,any answer will help me lot.

Comment: You have 2x `<script src=jquery` - the second will overwrite any plugins from the first (jquery-ui) - having said that, you do have jquery-ui twice as well...

Comment: I commented the other lines and it's still not working

Comment: I would review the HTML Source and Console. Make sure that all libraries load properly and that none are interfering with others. The error means that jQuery UI is not loading.

Comment: Yes, I have used some more plugins from Jquery and that's was the result when i tried to  use the full version of jQuery and jQuery UI. Was a conflict there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved, I have moved all the jQuery code in app.js, I have run the command

```
npm install jquery-ui --save-dev
```

and I imported it in app.js like :

```
import $ from 'jquery';
window.$ = window.jQuery = $;
import 'jquery-ui/ui/widgets/autocomplete.js';
```

IMPORTANT ! note that the autocomplete.js from the ends is work for me because is the widget that I want to use , find out what widget you want and import it there after importing jquery :

```
Import 'jquery-ui/widgets/here is the widget that you want .js'
```

But before look to not import jquery anywhere else like layouts or any other js files like bootstrap.js for example.